# Regex split numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a string of hexadecimal numbers `030c3f0f020039` but I want to split the number in following pattern `03 0c3f 0f 02 0029` and convert them to integers. For example:

```
Message type = 0x03 = 3 (in decimal format)
("030c3f0f020039" , 8-bit unsigned integer)
Battery voltage = 0x0c3f = 3135 millivolts = 3,135 volts (in decimal format)    
("030c3f0f020039" , 16-bit unsigned integer)
Test messages left = 0x0f = 15 (in decimal format)
("030c3f0f020039" ,  8-bit unsigned integer)
Alarm sequence = 0x02 = 2 (in decimal format)
("030c3f0f020039" ,  8-bit unsigned integer)
Sensor AD-value = 0x0039 = 57 (in decimal format)
("030c3f0f020039" , 16-bit unsigned integer)
```

Comment: Argh.. My eyes!... ah thank you ctwheels

Comment: Please verify the changes I made are appropriate. Also, please see [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: for the first one try `parseInt('030c3f0f020039'.slice(0,2), 16)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach:

```js
const source = '030c3f0f020039';
const numbers = source.match(/0+[1-9a-f]+/g).map(num => parseInt(num, 16));
console.log(numbers);
```

With regex, you match parts of string that start with one or more zeroes, followed by any number of non-zero digits or `a-f` letters. Each part is converted from hexadecimal to decimal with `parseInt(..., 16)`.

---

Still, this approach is far more direct than it should be: what if a value has meaningful 0 *inside* its hexadecimal representation? Looking at '03030f', we won't be able to deduct whether or not we have one, two or three values coded in that string.

The better way is using fixed-length 'fields'. For example, in this particular case 'Message type', 'Test messages left' and 'Alarm sequence' fields are sent as 8-bit unsigned integers (two hexadecimals), and 'Battery voltage' and 'Sensor AD-value' are sent as 16-bit unsigned integers (four hexadecimals). Taking this into account, we create a decypher:

```js
const fields = [
  { name: 'Message type',       range: [0, 2] },
  { name: 'Battery voltage',    range: [2, 6] },
  { name: 'Test messages left', range: [6, 8] },
  { name: 'Alarm sequence',     range: [8, 10] },
  { name: 'Sensor AD-value',    range: [10, 14] }
];

function decypher(message) {
  const data = fields.reduce((hash, {name, range}) => {
    hash[name] = parseInt(message.slice(...range), 16);
    return hash;    
  }, {});
  return data;
}

const message = '030c3f0f020039';
console.log(decypher(message));
```

Comment: I was about to answer: `"030c3f0f020039".match(/(0+[a-f1-9]*)/g)`

Comment: I think this will fail in many cases. 1) it uses leading zeroes to detect fields. What if the data doesn't start with a leading zero? 2) it doesn't match significant zeroes.

Comment: You're right, this solution is for very specific case described by the OP. The safest approach is ditching the limiters completely - and using the fixed-width fields for passing the values. I'll update my answer with this.

Comment: what if my hexadecimal does not start with "0" will it work?

Comment: The second snippet? Of course, as it doesn't depend on that characters at all. Can't help wondering, btw, where's that string come from.